# MSBuild is being run from within the "Visual Studio Command Prompt"

Tags: c#, .net

I am using VS2017 Enterprise for first the time building my repository. Have cloned code from my VS repository and trying to build it but build failed.
And also i have set environment variable path --> 
PATH : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

Error message :

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   MSBuild could not locate the Code Analysis tool at
>   'Drive:\Repo\NugetPackages\CarbonV2.FxCop.SDL.14.0.23107.0\Tools\FxCopCmd.exe'.
>   If MSBuild is being run from within the "Visual Studio Command
>   Prompt", specify the path to the Code Analysis tool by setting the
>   FXCOPDIR environment variable.    Demo.Service.Common

Could you please help on this, did i missed any thing?

Answer (score 0):

What's standing out to me is that i'm seeing NugetPackages - leading me to believe you're missing something from Nuget.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages-automatically-using-visual-studio

You can install the FXCOP manually, or follow the instructions in that article to have NuGet attempt to get all of the missing packages automatically for you. Hope this helps!